# Prove self-adjoint by symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, products

Let A be a 3x3 matrix and M be the matrix representation of my inner product.

I have to check if the map associated to A is self-adjoint.

This means: $$\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle$$.

Now would it be enough to prove that M (matrix reprensentation of my inner product) is symmetric? Does then follow that it is self-adjoint.

Comment: Since a scalar product is symmetric, it's matrix is symettric since $(A)_{ij}=\left<e_i,e_j\right>$ where the $e_i$ form a basis.

Comment: So it is self-adjoint? And the reason is that A can be written as <e_i, e_j>?

Comment: yes it is......